# htaccess rules not applied?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

So here is the full .htaccess file, with code added to redirect all urls/pages to the only accessible page of the site, except content, includes and admin ones:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


# BEGIN Custom

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Redirect all except given page/url to given website address
## src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176472/htaccess-redirect-all-links-except-base-url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page-accessible/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-includes/
RewriteRule .* https://molhokwai-tests.cloudaccess.host/page-accessible/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END Custom
```

But it only redirects root.

Can someone please explain? Is there a better way to do this?

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Your rules are in the wrong order. Your "Custom Redirect" needs to be at the top of the `.htaccess` file *before* the WordPress front-controller, ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

By placing it after the WordPress code block it will only get processed for requests that map directly to files and directories (including the document root, but excluding `/index.php`). (Although your custom redirect actually excludes the root, by the first *condition*?)

---

**UPDATE:**

> but `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/page-accessible/` is ignored, so the page is also redirected... ?

Well, it's not "ignored". However, the request is then internally rewritten to `index.php` (the WP front-controller) by the later rule and it's this that is then redirected on the second pass through the rewrite engine (which makes it *look* as if the above *condition* is being ignored).

You need to either:

- Exclude `index.php` by adding another *condtion* to your rule. For example:

  ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
   :
  ```

OR,

- Make sure the rule is only applied to direct requests from the client and not internally rewritten requests by the later rewrite. For example:

  ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   :
  ```

  The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP response status) after the later rewrite.

Comment: Hello @MrWhite   -   **Thanks**   -   I've put the rules before the Wordpress section. Now other rules are correctly enforced, but `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/page-accessible/` is ignored, so the page is also redirected... **?**

Comment: @MayouNkensa Ah, the request is being rewritten to `index.php` and it's this that is actually redirected. You need to add another _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) - I've updated my answer.